# How do I change request attributes in Java servlet to redirect a page?

Tags: java, servlets

I am creating a survey using JSP and a Java servlet.  In the JSP, I have a form and the "Next" button specifies the next question to go to: "/survey?q=2" where "q" is the parameter specifying the question to display.  However, depending on the answer (or lack-of), I may want to redirect to an error page, or go back to the same question.

I tried a simplified version where if the "answer" was null (answer being the name of the control allowing me to get the value), I would set the "q" parm using `request.setAttribute()` to same question number.  This, however, did not seem to overwrite the value of "q", as the next question would load instead of redirecting to the same question.

I also tried using the `response.sendRedirect()` and passing the desired url, but this threw an exception "Cannot forward after repsonse has been committed".

Here is an excerpt of the servlet:

```
    // At this point, the URL is /survey?q={SOME#} where SOME# is the next question to
    // go to after the submit.  So if the user was on Question 1, the submit location
    // would be /survey?q=2
    try {
        nextQuestion = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("q"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Inside the catch");
    }

    // The question we came from, obviously, is nextQuestion - 1        
    currQuestion = nextQuestion - 1;

    // This IF is just because I'm handling the first question differently
    if (currQuestion > 1) {
        answer = request.getParameter("answer");
        System.out.println("Answer = " + answer);

        //This function checkAnswer() returns "invalid" if no answer was selected"
        checkStr = checkAnswer(currQuestion, answer);
        if (checkStr == "invalid") {
            dispatcher = "survey-template.jsp";
            request.setAttribute("q", String.format("%d", currQuestion));
        } else {
            dispatcher = "survey-template.jsp";
        }
    } else {
        dispatcher = "survey-template.jsp";         
    }

    request.getRequestDispatcher(dispatcher).forward(request, response);
```

So the big question is: how can I redirect a page from the servlet?  If the request coming in is to go to `/survey?q=2`, and instead I want to go back to `/survey?q=1`, what do I need to do to make this happen?

Hopefully that was detailed enough.  I can provide more if needed.
Thanks!

Comment: One issue I see is, checkStr == "invalid" should be "invalid".equals(checkStr);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I also tried using the `response.sendRedirect()` and passing the desired url, but this threw an exception "Cannot forward after repsonse has been committed"

Looks like you tried to redirect to a new URL that will write a new response based on the URL content and close this stream, but kept the forwarding code that will try to write into the response, which isn't allowed since the response was already written and the stream closed. In code:

```
//having both is not allowed
//you should only use one of these approaches
response.sendRedirect(<someUrl>);
request.getRequestDispatcher(dispatcher).forward(request, response);
```

If you just want to redirect to another URL, use `response.sendRedirect(<someUrl>);` and make sure there's no further redirect nor forwarding. So, your code may be:

```
response.sendRedirect(<someUrl>);
//request.getRequestDispatcher(dispatcher).forward(request, response);
```

Just take into account that sending a redirect means to invoke a new GET request on the URL, so all the request attributes will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

After using `response.sendRedirect()` you should exit the method.

You can try:

```
response.sendRedirect("url");
return;
```